# Спор и спориться

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Дело спорится" - это значит, что работается легко и все хорошо получается. "Споро" - значит "быстро". Но в то же время, спорить - это уже совершенно другой процесс, в некоторой степени противоположный первому. По крайней мере, имеющий негативный оттенок.
Интересно было бы узнать: это просто омонимы или слова одного корня? И, если второе, то как вышло, что у них настолько разные значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Споро - от **пора**, то есть дело делается хорошо, вовремя, удачно и с пользой. Споро значит не скоро, а так как надо, с толком. *Спорынья* :

> От порядку и догляду спорынья в хозяйстве живет.
> Без Божьего благословенья, ни в чем спорыньи не жди.
> Спорынья (или спорина) в квашню! (привет вошедшего); ответ: Сто рублей в мошну!

Сейчас *спорынья* имеет совсем другое значение (вредитель злаков).

Спорить, спор, спорщик - от *переть*, то есть супротивничать, противоречить. *Будет буря, мы поспорим и помужествуем с ней*.
Дополнение.
Родственные слова : прение, пря (ссора, спор, тяжба), распря, препираться.

Comment: >Споро значит не скоро, а так как надо, с толком.

Забавно, что например в Хорватии слово *"споро"* означает *"медленно"*.

Comment: По-сербски, по-моему, тоже.